# How to use dynamic SQL for updating the query with multiple conditions?

Tags: sql, azure, dynamic, azure-active-directory, asset-pipeline

I am trying to execute below procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE UFP_PROCEDURE
    (@table_name1 varchar(100))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql varchar(200);

    SET @sql = 'UPDATE' + @table_name1 +
               'SET' + QUOTENAME(operation) +  '=' + 'U' + 'where' + QUOTENAME(last_updated_time) + 'IS NOT NULL' + 'AND' + QUOTENAME(last_created_date) + 'IS NOT NULL' + 'AND'  + QUOTENAME(delete_flag) + 'IS NULL'

    EXEC(@SQL)
END
```

I am not getting how to use dynamic SQL with all the single quotes and the columns which are in `QUOTENAME` is giving as invalid columns.

Here `@table_name1` is the table name which I am passing from Azure pipeline.

If anyone can give solution..... it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are issues in your dynamic query due to incorrect spaces and incorrect QUOTENAME, change your query like following.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE UFP_PROCEDURE(@table_name1 varchar(100))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql varchar(200);

   set @sql = 'UPDATE ' + quotename(@table_name1) +
    ' SET  operation = ''U'' where last_updated_time IS NOT NULL AND last_created_date IS NOT NULL AND delete_flag IS NULL'

    EXEC(@SQL)
END
```

**Note**: Instead of `EXEC`, you can always check your query using `print(@SQL)`

Comment: Thank you PSK! that's great

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE UFP_PROCEDURE
    (@table_name1 varchar(100))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql varchar(200);

    SET @sql = 'UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(@table_name1) +
               'SET operation= ''U'' where last_updated_time IS NOT NULL AND last_created_date IS NOT NULL AND delete_flag IS NULL'

    EXEC(@SQL)
END
```